# MacOS: where to install global application data with r/w access

Tags: macos

To where a pkg installer package on MacOS should install global application data ? All users of this specific system as well as the app itself should have read and write access to this data. Atm I install it to **/Library/Application Support/"mycompany"/"MyApp"** and modify the permissions. Is this a good practise for all MacOS versions ?

Thank you !

EDIT:
Meanwhile I have tested to r/w access files in this directory on Sierra and Mojave. It works like a charm when I set the permissions in my custom library folder recursively with **chmod -R 777** (well, less would be enough).
BTW I do this with a batch post installation shell script in the **packages app** [here](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html). It's a great UI based app (instead of using a bunch of command line tools). Building the pkg can be automated by a single command line: /usr/local/bin/packagesbuild /path/to/the/project.pkgproj, so integration into a flawless workflow is easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The only change I'm aware of related to this was in 10.7 when Apple changed the /Library folder to a hidden directory. (unlisted in finder unless specified) The path remains unchanged.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/MacOSXDirectories/MacOSXDirectories.html

Comment: Thank you for the link, it's helpful, especially the first hyperlink in the text. I have edited my question and have added my test results + some hints.